# Local discs not showing on Windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my system. Windows is installed on local drive C: whereas Ubuntu was installed on local drive F:

During the installation procedure of Ubuntu, initially I gave local drive D: as my swap space disc. However, when the installation manager prompted me that all my data on local disc D: would be formatted I went back and removed the local drive D from swap space.

Now my problems is that after installation of Ubuntu local disc D: is not being shown in Windows 10 however its content does appear on Ubuntu. I have checked disc partition panel in Windows. The drives are showing there but I cannot access them. Meaning upon right click only an option of delete is activated. Every other option is greyed out.

How to move the local disc D: from Ubuntu to Windows now?

[image: disk management]

Answer (score 1):

First, drive letters (`C:`, `D:`, `F:`, and so on) are Windows-specific. Ubuntu does not identify partitions or disks in this way. These identifiers also don't make clear whether the devices are multiple partitions on a single disk, separate physical disks, or a combination of both. These issues don't make it impossible to answer your particular question, but you should be aware of the fact that a Windows drive letter is likely to be useless when approaching an issue from Ubuntu (or any Linux distribution).

I'm not 100% positive, but I suspect that your Windows `D:` partition's type code has been changed. This will make it invisible to Windows, but Ubuntu won't care about that detail. The solution is to use a partitioning tool to change the type code. I'm not sure how to do this from the Windows Disk Management tool, or if it's even possible with that tool. From Ubuntu, you'd use either `fdisk` or `gdisk`, but which tool you use depends on the partition table type:

- **Master Boot Record (MBR)** -- With the older MBR system, you'd use `fdisk`, and change the type code of the partition from 0x82 to 0x07:

  1. Launch `fdisk` on the disk, as in `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`.
  2. Type `p` to view the partitions and identify the one you want to change. Because Linux doesn't use Windows drive letters, you'll need to identify the partition by its size and location.
  3. Type `t` to change the partition's type code. `fdisk` will prompt you for information, such as the partition number and type code. Change the type code to `07`.
  4. Type `w` to save your changes.
- **GUID Partition Table (GPT)** -- To modify the newer GPT, you can use either `gdisk` or *recent* versions of `fdisk`. Either way, the procedure is the same as with MBR, except that the type code will be different -- `11` if you use `fdisk` or `0700` if you use `gdisk`.

***WARNING:*** `gdisk` will convert a disk from MBR to GPT automatically. Thus, you should use `gdisk` only if you're positive that your disk already uses GPT. It's not 100% clear from your screen shot whether that's the case, but my suspicion is that your disk uses MBR, since I don't see any evidence of an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) on the disk. OTOH, the vast majority of computers that shipped with Windows 10 use GPT, so maybe I'm missing something. You can determine your disk's partition table type from the Windows disk properties dialog box, as described on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootmode.html#parttable) If you're unsure of this detail, it's best to stick with `fdisk` for this task; however, be aware that you need a recent version of `fdisk` to handle GPT. Ubuntu began shipping `fdisk` with GPT support beginning with Ubuntu 14.10 or 15.04, IIRC, so you should have that unless you're trying to install a rather old version of Ubuntu.